# Router navigate is not working in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have setup routing in my angular project and below are my routes in root module

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: DashboardComponent }
];
```

In my `app.component.ts` i have places my `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`.

In my login page I have a function which navigates to `http://localhost:4200/dashboard` once successful logging in

login.component.ts

```
login() {
....
this.router.navigate(['dashboard'], {relativeTo: this.route});
....
}
```

Now the problem here is when I do `ng serve` and open `localhost:4200` in the browser, I will not be able to login. Only after reloading the page i.e., `localhost:4200` I will be able to login.

What is stopping me to login here without reloading? please let me know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think when you try to navigate to route 'dashboard' the guard of routing rejects your action because maybe not a valid token or some logic in AuthGuard. You must check your AuthGuard